# Bootstrap : grid with variable number of columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a divider between the columns in my grid.
The thing is, I can have between 1 and 4 columns. In the case I do only one, I don't want any divider.

Here is the current code I do have :

```
<div class='col-md-{$ NumberOfColumns $} my_class' data-ng-repeat='...'>
 </div>
```

In the css, I can add something to my_class as :

```
.my_class {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(196, 187, 159, 0.63);
}
```

However, this border will appear even if I do have one column. Does bootstrap provide something to handle the divider more gently ?

Comment: You can use condition. You need to add `my_class` only when `NumberOfColumns` having value greater then 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector to "not" select elements that are the "only child" (i.e. single columns) like so:

`selector:not(:only-child){}`

Here is a snippet showing this code in action.

```css
div{clear:both;}

.col{
  width:100px; 
  background: yellow;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  clear:none;
  }

.col:not(:only-child){border-left:5px solid red;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col">1 col</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="col">1 col</div>
  <div class="col">2 col</div>
</div>
```

You can see that the row with only one column does not get the left border, while the row with more than one column does get the left border.